# Can I use two versions of SQLDeveloper on a single machine?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have SQLDeveloper Version 4.1.1.19 installed on my machine. If I would install the latest version of SQLDeveloper would my current one be affected? I don't want to mess up my current version but to be able to use both accordingly to my needs.

I don't mean running them both at the same time. I want to be able to run one or the other. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure can. Just don't expect preferences to be shared as they are stored in version aware directories.

Comment: @dsafas fsafasfsa  I have approx 15 versions of SQLDev 'installed' right now on my machine, and have as many as 3 of them running at any given time. You should be fine just - always always always put a new version in a fresh directory.